# DropShadowEffect в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне стало интересно, возможно ли без фигур сделать подобный эффект?

(слева - то, что я ожидаю; справа - то, что получается в WPF)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка взята с интернета.

Конкретный пример в WPF.
Вот, например, есть Grid с Border.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Grid Margin="0 0 0 10">
                        <Border>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="AliceBlue"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"
                                                  Color="Black"
                                                  ShadowDepth="0"/>
                            </Border.Effect>
                        </Border>
<!-- Разметка -->
</Grid>
```

Проблема в том, что при установке прозрачности самого фона, при установленном эффекте отбрасывания тени, тень отображается за фоном.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Grid Margin="0 0 0 10">
                        <Border>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#7FF0F8FF"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"
                                                  Color="Black"
                                                  ShadowDepth="0"/>
                            </Border.Effect>
                        </Border>
<!-- Разметка -->
</Grid>
```

Мне хочется сделать так, чтобы эта тень не отображалась за фоном, а только отбрасывалась от краёв.

Comment: Какая тень? Где тут хоть где-то есть тень? Ничего не ясно. Хочешь что бы было как слева - установи на правой половине фон какой-то под белый фон. А при установленной галочке(как на картинке) убирай этот фон в принципе.

Comment: XAML покажите, ничего не понятно. Пока понятно что вы хотите непрозрачный полупрозрачный, что в принципе нонсенс. И непонятно, зачем. С точки зрения восприятия пользователем оно невыглядит прозрачным, слева. Положите сзади непрозрачную подложку желтого цвета, и дело с концом.